# Javascript out function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function foo(arg, ajaxcomplete) {
    $.ajax({
    //ajaxcall...
    success: function() {
        //set ajaxcomplete to true
    }
}
```

Is there any way to do something similar to know when an ajaxcall has completed in a function? Thanks

Comment: Why not just do what you need to do on success in the `success` callback? You could even pass a function in to be called on success. IMO, setting a flag on success to notify when the AJAX is complete goes against the callback model that you're working with.

Comment: Can you clarify? Maybe include some psuedocode describing the sort of thing you would like to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes `complete`. it's fired after the error or success callbacks.

```
    function foo(arg, ajaxcomplete) {
        $.ajax({
            success: function() {
                alert('O.K.');
            },
            complete: function(){
                alert('We are done');
            }
        });
    }
```

Description from the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> complete(jqXHR, textStatus)Function, Array
>   A function to be called when the request finishes (after success and error callbacks are executed). The function gets passed two arguments: The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHTTPRequest) object and a string categorizing the status of the request ("success", "notmodified", "error", "timeout", "abort", or "parsererror"). As of jQuery 1.5, the complete setting can accept an array of functions. Each function will be called in turn. This is an Ajax Event.

Comment: The major problem with you solution is that it does not respond at all to the problem. $.ajax() being asynchronous, the method Foo() has (very very very most probably) already returned and so it is too late to set the value for "ajaxcomplete" parameter - either in success or complete callback.

Comment: @DidierGhys. He just need to move his code to the complete callback.

Comment: The complete callback is executed at the end of the ajax request, successful or not, you're right. But for this problem, setting a value to the parameter "ajaxcomplete" in any of those callbacks will have no effect because the method foo() will have returned already.

Comment: @DidierGhys He just need to move his code that need be executed after the ajax completed to the `complete` callback. I can't really understand what is it that you disagree about.

Answer (score 1):

The `success()` function is still the method to know that your AJAX call has completed. Even if wrapped in a function, it still happens asynchronously, and in your case, function `foo()` will have probably already completed and returned before the `success()` function is called.

Comment: success isn't enough. When an error occurred it won't get fired. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `complete` event to set the required variable because it is triggered no matter if the request is successful or failed with error.

```
function foo(arg, ajaxcomplete) {
    $.ajax({
    //ajaxcall...
    success: function() {

    },
    complete: function(){
        //set ajaxcomplete to true here
    }
}
```

Comment: He downvoted almost all the answers here. I've a bad feeling it's one of the other answer owners here.

Comment: Such people should be thrown out of SO.

Comment: You can ask one of the SO team to find out if my feeling is right. team@stackoverflow.com

Comment: @gdoron Hope you don't think it was me since I didn't get a downvote. You all got my +1's

Comment: @Michael - May be because @downvoter doesn't like `complete`!

Comment: @Michael. Actually I think it's some one else here _(Edit, he deleted his answer)_... thanks for your +1... =)

Answer (score 0):

You could have the `ajaxComplete` parameter as a callback:

```
function foo(arg, ajaxcomplete) {
  $.ajax({
    //ajaxcall...
    complete: function() {
      ajaxcomplete();
      // Some other code here if required
    }
  }
```

Which you could call like so:

```
var isComplete = false;
foo('someArg', function() { isComplete = true; });
```